# How to instal older version of liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

How to instal older version? I want to install 3.6.3.
I can not find it anywhere.

I used `brew install liquibase` and it installed latest version

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I downloaded the tar file from https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases/tag/liquibase-parent-3.6.3

and put it at specific path.

Then executed it as below:

```
/Users/thejavaguy/liquibase-3.6.3-bin/liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --changeLogFile=/Users/thejavaguy/workspace/change.yaml --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db" --classpath=/Users/thejavaguy/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar --username=root --password=unknown generateChangeLog
```